# How to allow App Engine to authenticate and download private Go modules

Tags: google-app-engine, go

My project uses Go modules hosted in private GitHub repositories.

Those are listed in my go.mod file, among the public ones.

On my local computer, I have no issue authenticating to the private repositories, by using the proper SSH key or API token in the project’s local git configuration file. The project compiles fine here.

Neither the git configuration nor the .netrc file are taken into account during the deployment (`gcloud app deploy`) and the build phase in the cloud, so my project compilation fails there with an authentication error for the private modules.

What is the best way to fix that? I would like to avoid a workaround which would consist in including the private modules’ source code in the deployed files, and have rather find a way to make the remote go or git use credentials I can provide.

Comment: I would suggest you to just [mirror the github](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository) repo to a cloud repo, then reference the cloud repo on your App Engine deployment

Answer (score 0):

You could try to deploy it directly from a build. According to the [Accessing private GitHub repositories](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos), you can set up git with key and domain on one of the build steps.

After that you can specify a step to run the `gcloud app deploy` command, as suggested in the [Quickstart for automating App Engine deployments with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories#create_a_cloudbuildyaml_file).

An example of the **cloudbuild.yaml** necessary to do this would be:

```
# Decrypt the file containing the key
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - kms
  - decrypt
  - --ciphertext-file=id_rsa.enc
  - --plaintext-file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
  - --location=global
  - --keyring=my-keyring
  - --key=github-key
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh

# Set up git with key and domain.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    cat <<EOF >/root/.ssh/config
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    EOF
    mv known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh

# Deploy app
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "16000s"
```